# Processing user registration/data after payment is made?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment

I have a `<textarea>` along with user registration information that I only want to be processed (inserted to the database) after payment (I want to keep my database clear unnecessary registrations or things like people that register but change their mind about paying for the site services)

I mean, I could use sessions but are there any other ways?

I was looking for a gateway that'll pass these variables back to me after purchase.

Or perhaps just having the gateway API.

Now, I know gateways such as paypal allow advanced processes like these but I don't want to apply to their credit checks just in case they have a reason to reject me. I don't want to depend on one gateway, is there any other gateways that guarantee not to reject my gateway needs and allow me to make advanced processes like the ones mentioned above? If anyone knows about gateways that don't need credit-type checks to be accepted I would appreciate if one could be suggested.

Note: I know some people will suggest to keep the registration data since it's only a few kilobytes even if people won't use the site or pay for the services. Call me OCD but I like my database clean and to only have relevant users/data. I will end up doing this in the end if I don't find a solution that suits my needs, so please, don't suggest it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use simple form based integration, you aren't going to get around having rows in your table before the users has been processed, unless you want people stealing your service. The fact you want your "database clean" is naive. Just put a registered flag and delete periodically if you are really that OCD.

You must create a auth token (random unique string), and update the database of the current user that that token belongs to that user. You then pass the user to the payment gateway and also pass along the token you have assigned to that user.

The gateway will send the user back to a url of your choosing, along with the token you have assigned to that user. At this point you update the table for that user with that token.

Only you and the gateway know about the token, the user only sees it if they get a successful charge.

If you don't do this, anyone can find the url the gateway sends on successful charge, and just load it themselves, giving them free service.

Alternatively, you can use deeper integration, were you do a web service call to the payment gateway, if it succeeds, you update your row, if it fails, you don't. This subjects you to onerous [PCI compliance](http://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pcifaqs.php) regulations. Trust me you don't want to delve into that. Just avoid it and do not let your systems see any CC information.

Comment: That's the thing... I wanted to find a gateway that would allow me to do such token authentication other than Paypal. I wanted to know perhaps a list of which gateways are available that didn't involve credit checks preferably.

Comment: And thanks for mentioning the tokens, it's just that I doubt hackers find a need to steal services that will help them with computer problems... :)